# UIView not adjusting width according to subviews?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiview

I'm trying to creating a reusable `UIView subclass`, with a `UILabel` and `UIImageView` as `subviews`. My view subclass should adjust its width according to the label's width.

Here is my class-

```
class CustomView: UIView {
    private var infoLabel: UILabel!
    private var imageView: UIImageView!


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        infoLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect.zero)
        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        addSubview(infoLabel)
        addSubview(imageView)

        infoLabel.backgroundColor = .white
        imageView.backgroundColor = .gray
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        super.updateConstraints()
        infoLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        infoLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        // infoLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        infoLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        infoLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true

        imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
            equalTo: infoLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        //imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
            //equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        //imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 25).isActive = true
        imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true

    }
    internal func setText(_ text: String, andImage image: String){
        infoLabel.text = text
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
    }
}
```

and here is how I'm adding it to view -

```
let aView: CustomView = CustomView(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 144, width: 120, height: 31))
view.addSubview(aView)
       aView.setText("my testing label", andImage: "distanceIcon")
        aView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
```

I get the result like added image.(red is my custom view, white is label and gray is image)
[image]

Edit: It is working if add view in Storyboard and but if I try via code as mentioned above it is not working.

Comment: Do you set width constraint on CustomView ?

Comment: No, I initialized custom view with frame and added to view controller's view.(code shown in question)

Comment: You are missing the trailing constraint on imageview.
Try this:  imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true

Comment: tried this but its doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Put adding constraints code after  addSubview(infoLabel); addSubview(imageView) lines in the init method

Comment: @Rendel I added the constraints in init instead updateConstraints function. But still not getting the expected result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155692/discussion-between-bharat-and-rendel).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false on CustomView class instance as well:

> self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

Also add leading and top constraints on custom view to set it's position:

```
customView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 200).isActive = true
customView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 200).isActive = true
```

Don't forget to add trailing constraint on imageView:

```
imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```